# List doesn't save the values from ggplot in loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm trying to save all my ggplots after a loop.
If i plot within the loop each plot, there is no problems. 
But when I call them out of the loop, they all have the same "y" data.

Here is my code :

```
library(gridExtra)
PLOT <- list()

for (m in 1:4){
para <- subset(REG,Type==m)
P <- ggplot(para, aes(fill=para$Factor, y=para$Slope, x=para$Year)) 
P <- P + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
PLOT[[m]] <- P
}

pdf("variations.pdf") 
marrangeGrob(PLOT, nrow=2, ncol=2)
dev.off()
```

Do you have any idea why

Comment: Because you always use the same data  (= `para`) for the plots.

Comment: I don't recomend using `$` subsetting inside the `aes()` function, it is often inviting more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: where is type used?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my question. the "Type" was "para" in the script. I edited the question.